# Binding a object.object.prop without any class modifications

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have a prop like this `Details.Article.Location.Stock` and this I need to bind it to UI. but the problem is, this is coming from dlls and I don't have any accesses to that code. once i modify the value of `Details.Article.Location.Stock` from ViewModel it won't reflect on ui as `INotifyPropertyChanged` is not present `Details` class and also I don't don't want to create a new object just update one prop any solution for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At some point that object is going to have to be exposed via a view model property, i.e.:

```
public class YourViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public YourEntityClass Something {get; set;}
}
```

You're saying that you can't change `YourEntityClass`, so you'll have to implement INPC at this top level instead (i.e. the `Something` property). After that, every time you update a property inside the YourEntityClass you will need to manually signal that the entire object has been updated, i.e.:

```
RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Something);
```

It's a horrible solution, because it means your entire object will now update unnecessarily in the GUI, but it's basically your only choice given the constraints that you've set for yourself.

Comment: I just took a local prop and used that. as I don't want to update the entire GUI and can I implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in model class does it still fellow mvvm?

Comment: Opinions are divided about that. I personally think yes, there is nothing wrong with INPC in a model class because it's not functionality specific to view models and there are legitimate cases where models need to notify other layers in a well-structured architecture that their properties have changed.